# MSBuild not publishing dll.config of dependency for ClickOnce

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, clickonce

My C# projectA published via ClickOnce depends on projectB. I need the projectB.dll.config file for projectA to work. While MSBuild copies over projectB.dll.config to `projectA/bin/ConfigXY` correctly, it is not published. VisualStudio (2017) doesn't even show the file in Application->Publish->Application Files.

As a workaround, I added this to A.csproj:

```
<Content Include="..\projectB\bin\Release\projectB.dll.config"> 
  <Link>projectB.dll.config</Link> 
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory> 
</Content>
```

Now VS shows the file in the "Application Files" list, but this of course works only for the Release build config. Since I have lots of configs in project A that map to different configs in B, I cannot simple use `$(Configuration)` in the path.

I have found some suggestions to include `..\**\*.dll.config`, but that seems dangerous, as when both the Debug and Release folder exist (from a previous build), I might end up with the wrong one.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I’d like to post this as a comment, but due to the limitations, I post it as an answer and I am sorry for that.

I did some tests, and it seems, to include the `project.dll.config` file to be published(shown in Application > Publish > Application Files), we need to include this file to the projectA.

I guess you mean you want to use “..\XXX\XXX\Release\projectB.dll.config” path for Release build and use ““..\XXX\XXX\Debug\projectB.dll.config” path for Debug build without using `$(Configuration)` right?

Generally, MSBuild uses `$(configuration)` to switch the configuration mode, if it is not available for you, to my knowledge, from MSBuild side, it is hard or not possible to switch/match the configuration mode.

Comment: Since projectB is also built by MSBuild in the same run, and I can see the config used for projectB in the logs, I reckoned there must be a way to access it. Unfortunately, the connection between projectA's config and projectB's config is in the .sln file, not the .csproj file. What I need is something like ```$(projectB.Configuration)```. What I found is ```%(ProjectReference.Name)``` and ```@(_ResolvedProjectReferencePaths)```, but no config for the referenced project.

Comment: @user2727133 I check the [common MSBuild project properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019), still, don’t find any related properties that may meet your requirements.